# OpenJPA disabling create tables on startup

Tags: spring, openjpa

I must use an external database in a `spring` non web application.

How can i disable openjpa to try to create entity tables? My entities `EmailAddress` and `Message` has annotations "`@Entity`", i do not know if it is right.

```
<persistence-unit name="myPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
        <class>pack.EmailAddress</class>
        <class>pack.Message</class>
           <properties>
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kepsDb" />
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
                <property name="openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings" value="false"/>
            </properties>

        </persistence-unit>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings` property for your persistence.xml file.